# How to apply filter for Gmail watch push notification api

Tags: node.js, push-notification, gmail-api, power-automate

I am trying to subscribe/registering for push notification and push that to mine server. 
Here is what I am trying

```
axios.post(`https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/watch`, {
            "topicName": "projects/gpubsub/topics/subcription"
        }, util.authHeader(token))
```

The API is working correctly. Now I have some questions like

1. How to apply a [filter](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/filter_settings) like getting notified only with the particular user or subject. I have saw filters are using in Microsoft flow for Gmail
2. How to send extra data so that I can receive it in 
   **attributes** property on pushing notification to my server

Answer (score 0):

Filters are sent as part of optional parms.

```
watch (cb) {
const params = {
  userId: 'me',
  resource: {
    labelIds: ['INBOX'],
    labelFilterAction: 'include',
    topicName: configure.Google.TopicName
  }
};

this.gmail.users.watch(params, cb);
}
```

remember lableid is the id of the label not its name use [lables.list](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/labels/list) to find the ids.

I recommend you look into using the official Google apis node.js library rather than coding this yourself.

Comment: But how to add filter as optional param and also how to send extra data so that I can Identify subscription.Can you provide sample request

Comment: The code i gave you is an example using the optional parms.  If you really want to do it the hard way then its just parms you attach onto your reuqest.   labelIds=XXX&labelFilterAction=XXX&topicName=XXX   This might help you under stand how to use HTTP paramaters https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmethods.asp

Comment: I want to add custom filters( like subject contains hello rater )and default filters

Comment: You are limited to what it allows you to filter on you cant make it up.  subject is not one of the things you can filter on.

Comment: But is there possible to achieve by adding filters on subhect or body or to, cc etc like [filters](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/settings/filters)

Comment: Unless i have missunderstood your question it was about filters with **watch** not filters with user https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/watch  Please edit your question accordingly.

Comment: I want to apply a filter with watch so that subscription can be done only with specific emails. Is there is a way to do this?

Comment: Again the watch filters are limited you can only filter within lables you cant specify only some emails.     So again No you cant do what it is you want to do.

Comment: Ok, Thanks. Is there a way to send extra data so that I can receive in **attributes** in response

Comment: its very limited it only tells you that there is something there it doesnt tell you whats there thats your job.